# XPath selecting child-child node of following-sibling where the following-sibling has a specific value in a seperate child-child node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

As an example, my XML looks like:

```
<rss>
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>Story1</title>
            <images>
                <image>
                    <type>main</type>
                    <url>http://...</url>
                </image>
                <image>
                    <type>thumb</type>
                    <url>http://...</url>
                </image>
            </images>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Story2</title>
            <images>
                <image>
                    <type>main</type>
                    <url>http://...</url>
                </image>
                <image>
                    <type>thumb</type>
                    <url>http://...</url>
                </image>
            </images>
        </item>
    </channel>
 </rss>
```

My XSLT currently looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="channel/item">
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <b><xsl:value-of select="title"/></b><br/>
            <img><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="images/image[type='thumb']/url"/></xsl:attribute></img>
            <br/><br/>
            <b><xsl:value-of select="./following-sibling::item[1]/title"/></b><br/>
            <img><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="./following-sibling::item[1]/images/image[type='thumb']/url"/></xsl:attribute></img>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The result is that the first story has the correct `<title>` and the "thumb" image, however the second story has the correct title but the no image as the XPATH to select the image node `<xsl:value-of select="./following-sibling::item[1]/images/image[type='thumb']/url"/>` doesn't appear to have matched anything.

How can I pick out the `<url>` node of the `<image>` node of the following-sibling's `<images>` node that has a `<type>` node with the value 'thumb'?

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using? I tested your code at http://fiddle.frameless.io, and it appears to work as intended.

Comment: @joemfb I'm using software that runs on the cloud (tm). So I have no idea, it's a black-box, though I suspect something from .NET. I've tried using a heap of different XSLT online testers, none of them successfully get me any output, including what fiddle.frameless.io . Can you provide the full code you used for both?

Answer (score 1):

> The result is that the first story has the correct  and the
>   "thumb" image ...

No, actually the result is null, because the instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="channel/item">
```

does not match anything. If you change it to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
```

then everything will fall into place, I think. Though there are some puzzling pieces in there: do you only want to output the first two items?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was trying to provide the minimal code needed to illustrate the problem. There's a very good reason why I'm looping and only looking at the first item and the sibling, but I didn't want to throw more than what is needed to solve the problem. The problem being that I need to select the child-child node of the following sibling when another child-child node of that sibling contains a specific value.

Comment: @DavidMurphy Ok, so did you solve it? The thing is that there is no problem in the reduced code that you have posted (other than what I have pointed out).

Comment: It's not solved.
`./following-sibling::item[1]/images/image[type='thumb']/url`
isn't returning the second stories URL. But judging by a comment above, it may be a problem with the processor, in which case I need to work out an alternative...

Comment: @DavidMurphy Well, we can't solve a problem that we cannot reproduce; have a look at: http://xsltransform.net/jyyiVhk

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately it doesn't help me as I have no control over the processor or updating it.

Can you think of any other way to accomplish the same thing? I know that I can't simply output some HTML for position()=1 and then output another chunk for position()=2 because the two "stories" are nested together in a table, i.e. I end up with mismatched opening and closing tags.

Comment: @DavidMurphy I doubt the problem is with the processor. More likely, the real code is different from the one you have posted and the real issue lies inside that difference.

Comment: well that's the kicker. I just dropped my real XML and XSLT code and it worked. So my processor is definitely rubbish. Thanks to The Cloud (tm)